# Wordpress to Drupal: Wordpress Migrate

Tags: 7, migrations

I have a fresh install Drupal 7.34 on WAMP. Token and Pathauto are already installed. The Theme, if it is relevant, is Stanford Open Framework.

I have Wordpress_migrate, migrate, migrate_extras intalled and then included features, media and media_youtube as low level diagnostic.

I follow through the instructions to use wordpress_migrate that seem self-explanatory and get this string of errors

```
Passing a group object to a migration constructor is now deprecated - pass through the arguments array passed to the leaf class instead.
The DynamicMigration class is no longer necessary and is now deprecated - please derive your migration classes directly from Migration.
The field mapping arguments() method is now deprecated - please use subfield notation instead.
The field mapping arguments() method is now deprecated - please use subfield notation instead.
The field mapping arguments() method is now deprecated - please use subfield notation instead.
No migration found with machine name WordPressAuthor
No migration found with machine name WordPressBlogEntry
No migration found with machine name WordPressPage
No migration found with machine name WordPressAttachment
No migration found with machine name WordPressComment
Passing a group object to a migration constructor is now deprecated - pass through the arguments array passed to the leaf class instead.
The DynamicMigration class is no longer necessary and is now deprecated - please derive your migration classes directly from Migration.
The field mapping arguments() method is now deprecated - please use subfield notation instead.
The field mapping arguments() method is now deprecated - please use subfield notation instead.
The field mapping arguments() method is now deprecated - please use subfield notation instead.
```

The migration does seem to complete but the list of imports under the blog name is  0  0 0 throughout.

I can see that a partial XML file has been transferred from Wordpress.
I have also tried exporting the Xml file from Wordpress and uploading that. I get the same errors.

The string of red errors suggests the entire module is borked. Is that correct? In which case, what is the best strategy to migrate a Wordpress blog to Drupal.

If the module is not borked then any suggestions what I might have missed or misunderstood?

I clearly do not understand the underlying problem, so please do not bite my head off.  A clear orientation will be received with sincere gratitude though.

Comment: I've used the module a month or two ago to import 60+ posts to an already existing Drupal 7 site. The import went without any problems. So the module's not borked. Those don't look like 'errors' per se, rather notifications that some things are deprecated.

Comment: Looking at the issue queue for Wordpress Migrate, I found an issue exactly like yours: https://www.drupal.org/node/2151761 they suggest using the dev version of the module (from 2015) instead of the stable one (from 2012).

Answer (score 1):

The module is pretty borked.

Beebee is right.  When you install using Drush, you will get the latest non-dev Wordpress_migrate and the latest Migrate - clash!  You also get no warning about needing migrate_extras features and media.

So the trick is install the latest Migrate with Drush but as of today's date, download the latest dev version of Wordpress_Migrate.

I was able to download my blog from its url. It did hang and I exited expecting a mess but all the content is there.  As I am trying to sort out content, that suits me.

So the principles --
--download migrate, migrate_extras, media, features and ctools
-- manually download the dev version of wordpress_migrate

If your blog is large, be patient. If the download borks, then try to increase the execution time or try exporting your blog to a file from inside Wordpress, use the Wordpress file splitter and try uploading by file.

Thanks Beebee.

Comment: You can download dev version of modules using drush. The command is a bit more tricky but if you want to download 2.x dev version of migrate for example, then you do: `drush dl migrate-7.x-2.x-dev`